# MySQL to MySQL clone with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone know of a PHP script that will clone an entire MySQL database to another on another server? As a sort of backup?

Comment: I guess what I'm really looking for is something that will automatically detect teh number of tables, rows in each table, and then loop through them all, and do the appropriate create operation on a remote database.(Automatically) If so where do I get it, or ahow do I make phpMyAdmin do it?

Comment: You could adjust this: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-script-backup-copy-mysql-table/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have your PHP script run (with e.g. the exec() or system() call) something like

```
mysqldump -q -C --databases mydatabase | mysql -C -h othermachine
```

Add the appropriate flags to these commands for specifying credentials, etc.

Answer (score 6):

phpMyAdmin does this very well. Of course, if you had shell access, try this instead:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [database] > [filename]
```

Comment: I am not quite sure what to do with that.

Comment: It created file.But there are no any data. 0 bytes. Can you help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link. -

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

This page is titled

**MYSQL DUMP — A Database Backup Program**

It contains all the details.

Hope this helps you.