# Backup mysql database in ms-access format using php

Tags: php, mysql, backup

i am using **mysqldump** to backup the database available in **MySQL** using the **PHP** to the sql dump format which creates the .SQL file. if i want to view / check the backup file then i have to import it first in order to check/verify/view the data which takes a lot of time.

the issue/question is whether there is some way to **create the backup copy of the MySQL database in some other format** like MS-ACCESS etc **rather than sql dump .sql file ?**

it will make it easy to open and check the database backup files.

Comment: And you really expect something like MS-Access to be faster than a real sql server when checking the sql file? If it is just for a visual syntax check etc then why not simply use a decent text editor with syntax highlighting?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744171/mysql-to-mysql-clone-with-php

Comment: @arkascha i just need backup in ms-access format. i know it can't be as faster as mysql.

Answer (score 0):

In basic terms you cannot do that, mysqldump is literally a sql file which has insert statements which would insert the data, where as a Ms-access has a accdb which is where the data is actually stored.

The import you are running actually takes the sql file and inserts it into your access db.